# Understanding `sequence_`

Tags: haskell, monads

[All About Monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads) explains `sequence_`:

> The `sequence_` function (notice the underscore) has the same behavior as `sequence` but does not return a list of results. It is useful when only the side-effects of the monadic computations are important.

Then, looking at `TestSequence.hs`:

```
import Control.Monad

f :: String -> IO ()
f x = print x

run :: [String] -> IO ()
run xs = sequence_ . map f $ xs
```

I can run it:

```
λ: run ["foo", "bar"]
"foo"
"bar"
```

Is `sequence_` calling `unsafePerformIO` on each `IO ()` to get the result, i.e. the `()`?

And, is `sequence_` discouraged? Or is it, for the `IO Monad`, simply used "at the end of the world" to run a list of `IO` actions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not calling `unsafePerformIO` on each `IO ()` action. In fact, its type is not even specific to `IO`:

```
sequence_ :: (Monad m, Foldable t) => t (m a) -> m ()
```

In the old libraries, when it was specific to lists (rather than generic over all `Foldable`s), it was implemented in the following perfectly readable way:

```
sequence_ [] = return ()
sequence_ (x:xs) = x >> sequence_ xs
```

It is absolutely not discouraged; `sequence_` (and its big brother, `mapM_`) are extremely useful, to the point that it is even one of my motivating examples for why `Monad`s as an abstraction are useful.

Comment: `mapM_` is (for now) only the middle brother. The real big sister is `traverse_`. Eventually, `mapM_` may be redefined to be the same as `traverse_`.

Comment: In any case, none of these explain the `Monad` abstraction, since even `Applicative` is a bit strong for the job.

Comment: @dfeuer, so we need a type class for `*>`? What would that be named? `Sequencable`?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, that's too powerful, I think. `Monoid1` should work, right?

Comment: Ah, right, since all elements of the `Foldable` are of the same type.

Comment: So, per the old definition: `x >> sequence_ xs` - what happens for `IO a -> IO ()`? Since `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` is not used, how does a side-effect, in Haskell, "evaluate" via `IO a -> IO ()`? I'm trying to reason about the difference in `IO a -> a` versus `IO a -> IO ()`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I'm not sure I understand your question. However, some comments that may or may not help: 1. An example function of type `IO a -> IO ()` is this simple one: `\io -> io >> return ()`. This says, "given an `IO` action that produces some value, produce the `IO` action that performs it, then returns an uninteresting value instead". 2. `IO` actions are allowed to contain "subactions" which also do `IO`; however, non-`IO` values are not allowed to do `IO`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: you may benefit from reading [this article](http://blog.jle.im/entry/inside-my-world-ode-to-functor-and-monad).